# I can not delete a date in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, cursor

I have a problem to exclude a date and this occurs only when it is not the last element to the first in my ArrayList.

```
Why does this happen and how to solve?
Example:
| ID |
  :
 Gil <- problem deleting this line
 Rui <- problem deleting this line
 Ana <- no problem
```

> I'm implementing the example of this site: 
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
>
> error: Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Code

```
public Integer deleteContact (Integer id, ArrayList<Integer> array_List)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete("contacts", "id = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});

    db.close();
    return  id;
}


public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

---

```
public Cursor getData(int id){
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null       );
  return res;
   }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextStreet);
    street = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCity);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null)
    {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");

        if(Value>0){
            //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
                if ( rs.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        if (rs != null  && rs.getCount()!= 0 ){
                            id_To_Update = Value;
String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
String phon=rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE));
String emai=rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL));
String Stree=rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET));
String  plac = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY));

                            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            name.setText((CharSequence) nam);
                            name.setFocusable(false);
                            name.setClickable(false);

                            phone.setText((CharSequence) phon);
                            phone.setFocusable(false);
                            phone.setClickable(false);

                            email.setText((CharSequence) emai);
                            email.setFocusable(false);
                            email.setClickable(false);

                            street.setText((CharSequence) stree);
                            street.setFocusable(false);
                            street.setClickable(false);

                            place.setText((CharSequence) plac);
                            place.setFocusable(false);
                            place.setClickable(false);

                        }
                    } while (rs.moveToNext());

                        if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                            rs.close();
                        }
                }
            if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                rs.close();
            }

        }
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.Edit_Contact:
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            name.setEnabled(true);
            name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            name.setClickable(true);

            phone.setEnabled(true);
            phone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            phone.setClickable(true);

            email.setEnabled(true);
            email.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            email.setClickable(true);

            street.setEnabled(true);
            street.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            street.setClickable(true);

            place.setEnabled(true);
            place.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            place.setClickable(true);

            return true;
        case R.id.Delete_Contact:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }


                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Are you sure");
            d.show();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.Edit_Contact:
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            name.setEnabled(true);
            name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            name.setClickable(true);

            phone.setEnabled(true);
            phone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            phone.setClickable(true);

            email.setEnabled(true);
            email.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            email.setClickable(true);

            street.setEnabled(true);
            street.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            street.setClickable(true);

            place.setEnabled(true);
            place.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            place.setClickable(true);

            return true;
        case R.id.Delete_Contact:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }


                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Are you sure");
            d.show();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
```

the error leads me for the start of this line:

```
String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if rs.moveToFist() return false.

If it is false, it means the cursor is empty, so when you try to get the value you have an android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Your getData(int) return an empty cursor, because there is no record for the id you gave him.

To remove the data in your arrayList change :

```
array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
```

By :

```
int idContacts =res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_ID)); 
array_list.add(idContacts, res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
```

Then when you want to remove a contact use :

```
 array_list.remove(idDelete);
```

Comment: I think in the database, "id" s are deleted, but not within the arraylist, but not sure

Comment: I think the error is here because you try to get in the database a record for a specific id who doesn't exist. So if you don't check if your cursor is not empty, sometimes you will get  android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException on this line :
String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));

Comment: I'd better catch the elements that are in the database and then show in my arrayList ...